# Adjectives that can describe both a flavour and a personality

Tags: single-word-requests

I am trying to write a sentence to show the similarity between the taste of a cuisine and the people's characters, such as

*Influenced by the custom and culture, the local cuisine is as bland as the native people.*

Are there any other adjectives that can be used to describe both a taste/flavour and a personality?

Comment: Uh, "sweet", "bitter", "acidic", "spicy", "salty".

Comment: *Sour*, *distasteful*, *pleasant*, *fruity*, *scrumptious*, *nutty* …

Comment: It is up to the writer to use such adjectives to describe both in a believable way. Any adjective will do. It is up to you to choose the food and the character.

Comment: if one adjective cannot express both the way, then I have to a pair of adjectives to describe food and people, right?
e.g.
The taste of food is pure and natural as the local people who are sincere and honest.